# How to change destination path for amplify codegen models in Flutter

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, graphql-codegen

I follow [the tutorial](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#sample-schema) and managed to properly generate models. I wonder how I can choose the destination where models are generated. By default it is lib/models.

How can I change the destination and split generated files between different folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it is not possible, but the feature was requested and can be tracked [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-codegen/issues/55).

**Update 24.05.2023**.
as @rleffler mentioned now it is supported:

```
amplify codegen models --output-dir your/path
```

Unfortunately, models are still generated into `lib/models`when you run `amplify pull` so remember to removed them.

Comment: UPDATE: This is now supported. From the issue: This feature is now supported. You can specify an --output-dir when running amplify codegen models in order to specify where the files will be rendered. Marking this issue as closed.